# Cancel a experiment runs in AzureML using python

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

Found that some of the runs did not get failed and were in running state. I assume these might be consuming compute targets.
I tried to cancel the run which are in Running state from Azure ML Runs web UI, but was not working.

Answer (score 2):

First get the experiment object that have the Runs to cancel.

`experiment = Experiment.list(workspace=workspace_obj, experiment_name='experiment_name')[0]`

or

```
experiment = ws.experiments['experiment_name']
```

Cancel all runs which are in running state.

```
for run in experiment.get_runs():
    print(run.id)
    if run.status=="Running":
        run.cancel()
```

Again check the status of each run:

```
for run in experiment.get_runs():
    print(run.id)
    print(run.status)
```